# How to add properties to linq2Sql ORM Table

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

In my SQL table I have two properties, StartDateTime and EndDateTime, and in my code I have the Linq2Sql ORM table with it's mapped corresponding StartDateTime and EndDateTime. I decided to add a duration as such:

```
public TimeSpan Duration
{
   get
   {
      TimeSpan ts =(TimeSpan) (EndDateTime - StartDateTime);
      return ts;
   }
}
```

This works, but when I   modify my dbml file via the designer the additions of course disappear as the files are rewritten. 
My question is what would be a best practice for adding a duration property, I don't really want to add it to the source SQL Table as it seems redundant to have it there.

Update:
since the created ORM table is defined as "public partial class" I created an additional code file to keep my class additions in such as in the case of the added property "Duration".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entity class is a partial class. 
So you can place your property in a separate file, containing:

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
    public TimeSpan Duration
    {
        get
        {
            TimeSpan ts =(TimeSpan) (EndDateTime - StartDateTime);
            return ts;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also arrived as this conclusion as I went to coffee room to pour another.

Answer (score 0):

Do not modify the files that are automatically generated, add a new file to your project with a partial definition of your class

```
// File : MyTableClass_Extend.cs

public partial class MyTableClass
{
    public TimeSpan Duration
    {
       get
       {
          TimeSpan ts =(TimeSpan) (EndDateTime - StartDateTime);
          return ts;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I came to the same conclusion when I got up from my desk for a  shot of coffee.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using following:

TimeSpan duration = _MyEndDataTime.Subtract(_MyStartDateTime);

But remember, TimeSpan only able to hold time upto 11:59:59 (hh:mm:ss) so if the StartDateTime and EndDateTime more then 24 hours you will be stuck, so I recommand to use DataTime to get the duration instead of TimeSpan.

Comment: ?? Max Timespan: ~10 million days ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.maxvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx